# Automatic turning on an android

Tags: android, linux

i have found a solution of the problem of automatic turning on an android (not samsung), when battery is charging
for this i've inserting the line

```
/system/bin/reboot
```

in the file

```
/system/bin/ipod
```

on android 4.2 everything worked fine. now, i'm working on 4.4 Kitkat, and the same trick didn't worked. can you tell me, what could be the problem, and how to reach a final goal: automatically turn on the phone, when battery is charging?

Comment: Just want to thank you.I was all day trying yesterday to bootup my MTK device by modifying the ipod.But everywhere online they said to modify with these lines of code - #!/system/bin/sh su /system/bin/reboot,but in vain. When instead I just gave '/system/bin/reboot' my device rebooted :)

Comment: No problem :) What is your version Android?

Comment: My android version is 4.2.2(running on a tablet called iBall).Regarding the reboot,I observe that when I use the two lines of code -  '#!/system/bin/sh' and '/system/bin/reboot' within ipod,I am stuck at a charging symbol,whereas when I just use the latter it actually reboots.I have a feeling that when I use those two lines of code my execution stops at '#!/system/bin/sh'.I don't know why my code gets stuck at that.Any idea?

Comment: Also,consider a case wherein my tablets battery is fully drained and it has no juice at all.At this moment when I try to bootup my tab then it wont boot up instantly.But if I keep it for charging for a few minutes and try later then it boots up.So I need to give a delay/sleep before the reboot for such cases.Do you know how I can achieve that in the ipod file.PS: I tried 'sleep 20' '/system/bin/reboot' but it didnt work.

Comment: Found the reason my commands were not executing.
The reason was because,I was editing on my notepad++ on windows,until I came across this answer on SO -
" Make sure your text editor is not putting a /r /n and only a /n for every new line. This is typical if you are writing the script on windows.Use notepad++ (windows) and go to edit|EOL convention|UNIX then save it.  "
So I changed my convention as per the above answer and ran my code and got the desired result.

Comment: Okey, we know it work for android 4.2. 
I'm compare files /system/bin/ipod 4.2 and 4.4; they are identical.
But my solution, didn't work on kitkat =(

Comment: Did you finally make it on Android 4.4?