# Automatic turning on an android mtk

Tags: android, system, ipod

[Automatic turning on an android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834957/automatic-turning-on-an-android/26988190#26988190)

I have doogee dg550 and in /system/bin/ipod i give the line /system/bin/reboot but it is not any result :( I editing this file in android app "turbo editor" and next I shutdown the phone and plug charger. Any idea?

Comment: Better you check all the comments as your editor might be adding /n at the end of lines.

Comment: how can I check it? i understood that /n is no visible in the texts window.